# How to use custom types in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to make a modified version of the classic word count program, where the target output is the name of an input document and the number of unique words it contains.

To achieve this I planned to use a custom datatype to use as a key, where the datatype contains the name of an input file and a word. ie: DataStruct = [filename, word].

My plan is to do this in two passes, in the first I map the input files to (DataStruct, 1) key-value pairs, and then reduce this to -> (DataStruct, count).
I envision every line to be formatted like this:

```
..
file1 word 4
file2 word 6
..
```

I will then do another pass where the map phase produces (filename, 1) pairs and the reducer produces the desired (filename, count) output.

The first (and minor) question I have is whether this is a reasonable way to approach this problem, there isn't a lot of hadoop material available online for reference so I'd appreciate any pointers someone experienced in this field can give me.

The major question I have, and where the trouble I am encountering is, is in the output of my first phase. I expected after implementing the following class into my code that I would get the desired `file word count` output but it is not so.

```
    public static class DataStruct implements WritableComparable<DataStruct> {
        private Text word;
        private Text filename;

        public DataStruct(Text w, Text fn) {
            word = w;
            filename = fn;
        }

        public DataStruct() {
            word = new Text();
            filename = new Text();
        }

        public void set(Text w, Text fn) {
            word = w;
            filename = fn;
        }

        public Text getFilename() {
            return filename;
        }

        public Text getWord() {
            return word;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(DataStruct d) {
            if(word.compareTo(d.word) == 0) {
                return filename.compareTo(d.filename);
            }
            else return word.compareTo(d.word);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if(o instanceof DataStruct) {
                DataStruct other = (DataStruct) o;
                return word.equals(other.word) && filename.equals(other.filename);
            }
            else return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
            word.readFields(in);
            filename.readFields(in);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
            word.write(out);
            filename.write(out);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            String combine = word.toString()+filename.toString();
            return combine.hashCode();
        }

    }
```

My output instead looks like this:

```
..
UniqueWordsDocument$DataStruct@a3cd2dd1 1
UniqueWordsDocument$DataStruct@1f6943cc 1
..
```

and I can't find anything online that explains this. I have figured out that the value after the @ is the hashcode of the data but i do not know how to proceed without having the filename and word in the output. If someone can explain what is happening here and/or how to fix this issue I would be incredibly appreciative.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you in some way as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208454/hadoop-word-count-receive-the-total-number-of-words-that-start-with-the-letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the `public String toString()` method in your `DataStruct` class.

As things stand, Java has no idea how to display your `DataStruct` objects, and so just prints a reference to the objects themselves.

Your may want to have something like:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return word.toString() + "-" + filename.toString();
}
```