# Hadoop : Mapreduce not starting/running

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, apache-pig

**I'm new to Hadoop, Please help**

2019-10-07 18:44:46,563 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - HadoopJobId: job_1569922894111_0023 2019-10-07 18:44:46,563 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Processing aliases trip 2019-10-07 18:44:46,563 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - detailed locations: M: trip[1,7],trip[-1,-1] C: R: 2019-10-07 18:44:46,575 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - 0% complete 2019-10-07 18:44:46,575 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Running jobs are [job_1569922894111_0023]

This is what I got after using the command 'dump trip;', I have loaded the data and stored in trip. MapReduce is not running/starting I guess.

```
mapred-site.xml

<configuration>
        <property>
            <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
            <value>yarn</value>
        </property>

    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
            <value>1024</value>
        </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
            <value>1024</value>
        </property>

        <property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores</name>
            <value>2</value>
            <description>The number of virtual cores required for each map task.</description>
        </property>

         <property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.cpu.vcores</name>
            <value>2</value>
            <description>The number of virtual cores required for each map task.</description>
        </property>
    </configuration>


yarn-site.xml

<configuration>

    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.auxservices.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
       <value>0.0.0.0</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208454/hadoop-word-count-receive-the-total-number-of-words-that-start-with-the-letter. Maybe it could help you somehow with your problem

Comment: You need to open up the YARN UI and figure out if jobs are being accepted