# Count the key of the same object in MapReduce

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, count, mapreduce

So I got this issue where I`m trying to count the number of times an object/node is updated in MapReduce Hadoop. So my XML file looks like this. As you can see there are different node ids. I'm trying to count the total amount of versions for each unique ID but I`m a bit lost. Below you can see the MapReduce code and XML file.

```
</node>
 <node id="1024219306" visible="true" version="1" changeset="6558971" timestamp="2010-12-06T01:34:53Z" user="tusvik" uid="203227" lat="59.2079125" lon="10.9487952">
  <tag k="source" v="Bing"/>
 </node>

 <node id="1024219307" visible="true" version="2" changeset="6590128" timestamp="2010-12-08T22:03:37Z" user="jrj" uid="148636" lat="59.2099530" lon="10.9455866">
  <tag k="source" v="Bing"/>
 </node>

 <node id="1024219308" visible="true" version="1" changeset="6558971" timestamp="2010-12-06T01:34:53Z" user="tusvik" uid="203227" lat="59.2131168" lon="10.9433018">
  <tag k="source" v="Bing"/>
</node>
```

```java
public class CountMU{

    public static class TokenizerMapper
            extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String cb = itr.nextToken();
                if (cb.startsWith("<node")) {
                    String moveTonxt = itr.nextToken();
                        word.set(moveTonxt);

                }
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class IntSumReducer
            extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                           Context context
        ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }
            result.set(sum);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
    }
}
```

Whats the solid way to do count the amount of each different ID in the xml? A shortcut would maybe to count the highest number of the `version="x"` token for each Unique ID?

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate?

Comment: @BenWatson i tried that, but it doesnt include the amount of times that object has been updated(Im using the openstreetmap)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208454/hadoop-word-count-receive-the-total-number-of-words-that-start-with-the-letter . Maybe it could help you in some way.

Comment: What does this output vs what do you expect?