# Run hadoop function at runtime

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a problem, I'm trying to run map and reduce function at runtime. In my exemple I have a program that do something, while the program run, I need to use hadoop.

So can I , and if yes how, can use map and reduce function while the program is already in running? I need to pass some input to map function, but I see hadoop that use "job" to set input  and output (in WordCount exemple) like this:

```
        // Adding the Input path  
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(p0));  
        // Setting the output path  
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(p1));
```

I need to will give at map function a Double variable, and i don't need a really output because I will should took the output from reduce function.

Comment: Take a look at this question to see if this helps you in any way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208454/hadoop-word-count-receive-the-total-number-of-words-that-start-with-the-letter

Comment: not a lot, beacause i need to give a map function another input, not a file but a double variable, and the output, in the same way, i need to recive a double variable because i should use some other function in my program after the mapReduce.