# Hadoop and re-used mutable writable fields

Tags: java, performance, hadoop

Here's a snippet from an implementation of a word-count job posted from an Apache Tutorial

```
public static class TokenizerMapper  extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
        while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(itr.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any benefit to reusing the `Text word` field?

I've seen this done in many Hadoop programs, is instantiation of this class so heavy that reusing results in performance improvements. If not, why do people do it, as opposed to something like `context.write(new Text(itr.nextToken()), one);`

Comment: As opposed to what?

Comment: @PM77-1 Re-usage of the word field, as opposed to instantiating a Text object as needed

Comment: Clear DRY principle.

Comment: @PM77-1 How? Nothings being repeated.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you in some way as well, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208454/hadoop-word-count-receive-the-total-number-of-words-that-start-with-the-letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that the instantiation of a `Text` object is not heavy. However if you're processing billions of records then you want to shave every possible nanosecond per record. Every time you create a new `Text` object, Java has to allocate memory for it, keep track of it, and then garbage collect it at some point. This time really can add up in big jobs.

Comment: I think this micro-optimisation only adds to the complexity of the implementation. Most people brand new to Java / Hadoop probably wouldn't understand that you don't *have* to do this, but pick it up - like other code smells - and incorporate it everywhere else.

Comment: The cleanest code isn't always the most performant. I'd argue that no one new to Java should be writing MapReduce, but yes the official docs could have a comment explaining why they reuse `Text`.