# Getting numbers in hadoop word count example in cloudera

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, word-count

Below we have used the code: 
The map class is WCMapper.
the reduce class is WCReducer.

Not quite sure why the output is generating number instead of wordcount.

```
public class WCMapper extends Mapper { 
    public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws 
    IOException,InterruptedException 
       { String line = key.toString(); 
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line); 
          while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) 
          { value.set(tokenizer.nextToken()); 
           context.write(value, new IntWritable(1)); 
            }
            }

       }

 public class WCReducer extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable>{
private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)throws IOException,InterruptedException
{
    int sum=0;
    for(IntWritable x: values)
    {
        sum+=x.get();

    }

    result.set(sum);
    System.out.println("Key: "+key+"Value: "+sum);
    context.write(key, result);

}
   }    



public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "WordCount");

    job.setJarByClass(WorCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(WCMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(WCReducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

     Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

     FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
     FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

     outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath, true);

     System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)? 0: 1);
}
```

Input file:
This is cloudera
This is smart

Expected output:
This 2
is 2
cloudera 1
smart 1

Output obtained:
0 1
17 1

Comment: Maybe this question can help you in some way, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26208454/hadoop-word-count-receive-the-total-number-of-words-that-start-with-the-letter

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your mapper:

```
String line = key.toString();
```

The `key` in this case is a `LongWritable` representing the byte offset of the line in the file. If you change that line to `value`, and then don't use `value` below you'll get the right answer.

New mapper:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException { 
    String line = value.toString(); 
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line); 
    Text word = new Text();

    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(tokenizer.nextToken()); 
        context.write(word, new IntWritable(1)); 
    }
}
```