# calculating cpu usage in nodejs

Tags: node.js, cpu-usage

I'm trying to calculate the CPU usage on the computer running my nodejs app but for some reason the output is a lot higher than what my system monitor on ubuntu is showing me. Here is my code:

```
const cores = _.map(os.cpus(), 'times')
const free = _.sumBy(cores, 'idle')
const total = _.sumBy(cores, c => _.sum(_.values(c)))
const usage = free * 100 / total
console.log(usage)
```

This outputs ~89% whereas the system monitor shows that all of my CPUs are under 30%. I also tried calcualting it on just one core like this:

`console.log(cores[1].idle / _.sum(_.values(cores[1])))`

But this still showed a similar number that was way too high. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check out the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9567357/2746388).

The information provided by `os.cpu()` is an average usage since startup. To have information about the current usage of CPU, you could do something like this:

```
let cores = _.map(os.cpus(), 'times');
let freeBefore = _.sumBy(cores, 'idle');
let totalBefore = _.sumBy(cores, c => _.sum(_.values(c)));

setTimeout(() => {
  let cores = _.map(os.cpus(), 'times');
  let free = _.sumBy(cores, 'idle') - freeBefore;
  let total = _.sumBy(cores, c => _.sum(_.values(c))) - totalBefore;

  let usage = free * 100 / total;
  console.log(usage);
}, 500);
```